# Assigning a value to a valiable in powershell

Tags: powershell

This script is a part of a larger script.
I need to generate a variable based on a counter and then assign a value to that variable. So In this case I need to assign 24 to List_0.

```
$CountOutFile = 0
$("List_" + $CountOutFile) = 24
```

Any thoughts would be really appreciated.

Comment: *I need to generate a variable based on a counter* - most likely you don't need to, this is a common beginner-programmer mistake caused by not knowing enough to know better ways yet. Use a hashtable with that as the key and 24 as the value. `$data = @{}; $data["List_$CountOutFile"] = 24`

Comment: I have to read a 400,000 line file and each line has 20 variables to filter on. I need to evaluate the file in 60 seconds.  With the main script  as I add more lines to the $NotesList the script takes longer and longer. I believe .NET is duplicating the entire array in memory, adding the new item, and deleting the old copy in memory https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2017/07/12/slow-code-top-5-ways-to-make-your-powershell-scripts-run-faster/. So I need to split the additions into smaller parts with a counter.

Comment: `$array +=` does duplicate the entire array. The fix for that is to use `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` or `[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]` which behave better and add things faster.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What does your input look like (show a sample of the file, a couple lines should suffice), and explain what you need the input values for (i.e. what do you want to do with them after you assigned them to a variable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect @TessellatingHeckler is correct, but in the event that you really want to generate a variable with that name, it's easy to do with the `new-variable` cmdlet.  Also, concatenation is easier using interpolation...

```
New-Variable -Name "List_$CountOutFile" -value 24
```

If you need to add to an existing variable, you could do something like this:

```
$val=Get-Variable -Name "List_$CountOutFile" -ValueOnly
Set-Variable -Name "List_$CountOutFile" -value $val+$LineinFile
```

Comment: Mike, I would need to read the lines in a file using a FOR loop and add the lines to the variable we created .. something like $"List_$CountOutFile" += $LineinFile

Comment: Thanks Mike. I believe there was an extra -Name in the first line and the "+" is the second line was not needed. Other than that it worked great. Thanks !!!!